# Apple TV works with my iPhone but not with my PC on the same wireless network

Tags: iphone, windows, appletv, network, airplay

I have:

- Windows 7 PC with latest version of iTunes connected to my network (wired). Windows Firewall is turned off.
- Apple TV (2nd generation) connected to my network (wireless)
- iPhone connected to my network (wireless)

I am able to AirPlay from my iPhone to the Apple TV, but it does not work from my PC.

In the Apple TV menu under Computers, I can see my computer's library but when I try to connect, it takes a while and then it fails. I don't see the Apple TV from iTunes on the PC. (I don't see the iPhone either under sharing but I don't know if it should show up there or not).

I don't think it's a router issue otherwise it wouldn't work with the iPhone either.

I have reinstalled iTunes on the PC and rebooted all devices (router, PC, Apple TV).

What do you think could be the problem?

Comment: I don't have an Apple TV, but I suspect the problem is that you need to initiate a wireless connection from the PC to the AppleTV. If the PC is not on the wireless network, then this is not possible.

Comment: I tried it wireless too from the PC. It does not work either.

Comment: Are all these devices on the same iTunes account?

Comment: Yes, they are...

Comment: If iTunes does not see the Apple TV they may not be on the same network. Do you have an AirPort (i.e. Apple-branded) router? There are certain features on AirPort routers that may create a separate network if not careful. Also, was an iTunes Library with the same name previously associated with that Apple TV? You may need to re-create the link between the Apple TV and the PC (on which case, you will need iTunes to find the Apple TV first).

Comment: I have a Dlink router. All devices are on the same network. As I wrote, the Apple TV "sees" the PC but it's unable to connect to it. When I turn off iTunes on the PC, the PC name disappear on the AppleTv menu. Howerver the PC does not see the Apple TV at all.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: As I wrote in a comment to Temikus's answer, I bought a new PC and everything works perfectly on that PC. So the problem is with my laptop not with the router or network. My plan was to reformat the laptop to see if the problem would continue but I did not get a chance to do it yet.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a home sharing issue to me. I would check that the Apple ID you have set in iTunes on your PC matches the ID you have configured for home sharing on the Apple TV and that the password is correct for both.

Comment: It could be - but it might be better to check that mDNS isn't being blocked before looking at a narrow cause. Your suggestion is faster to check than mine, though :-)

Comment: I'm sure it is the same ID and password.

Comment: Still worth checking

Comment: I did not mean _I'm sure_ as _I think so_. I meant _I'm sure_ as _I know so_. I only have one apple ID. And I turned Home Sharing off and reconfigured it again just to make really really sure.

Comment: Ah ok, best of luck with the other suggestions then

Answer (score 1):

Okay, AirTunes uses a protocol that is different from AirPlay mirroring, used by the iPhone.

The AirTunes part of the AirPlay protocol stack uses UDP for streaming audio and is based on the RTSP network control protocol.

What I would do first:
1) Turn off QoS or any protocol-dependent traffic shaping on your router.
2) All apple technologies are bonjour-dependent, I would check if there if there is an avahi service running on your router, using one of the following apps:
http://hobbyistsoftware.com/bonjourbrowser
http://www.stg.com/zeroconf_explorer.html

Comment: I turned off `QoS` on the router. Then I used `Bonjour Browser` and the Apple TV is not listed.

Comment: I have found another thread here https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2747237?start=0&tstart=0 that points toward an issue with my D655 router.

Comment: Enabling `Multicast Streams` (as mentioned in that thread in my previous comment) did not help.

Comment: After enabling multicast, you need to reboot both the router and AppleTV. Did you do it? Also, please tell me your firmware version. Also, please  state the hardware revision in the upper right corner.

Comment: Yes I did reboot both. The Apple TV is still not showing in Bonjour Browser. The H/W Ver is A4 and I have the latest firmware installed (1.35).

Comment: I have an exact same router, it truly does have some issues. Maybe some configuration file is screwed up. To clear all config files you must do a 30/30/30 reset. Here's how: 1) With the unit powered on, press and hold the reset button on back of unit for 30 seconds
2) Without releasing the reset button, unplug the unit and hold reset for another 30 seconds
3) Plug the unit back in STILL holding the reset button a final 30 seconds. This should clear the NVRAM completely (keep in mind that it will delete ALL the settings).

Comment: After - configure the device again (don't restore the settings from a file, because if there was a screwed up table, it will be uploaded again), turn off QoS and try to find AppleTV again. If you can't - turn on multicast, reboot the router, reboot the AppleTV and try again. If all of the above doesn't help, you need to check with D-Link support, maybe they'll give you a beta firmware or recommend to go back to some specific version.

Comment: Well guess what? I have just received my new PC today. I installed Windows and iTunes; playing on my Apple TV works like a charm (same network, same ID). I did not even turn the Windows Firewall off; iTunes configured it correctly while installing. Conclusion: my laptop has a problem. I'll reformat the laptop this weekend and will let you know.

Comment: I did not have time to reformat the laptop yet but I'm giving you the bounty award anyway cause you advice was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to troubleshoot this will be to get [WinDump](http://www.winpcap.org/windump/) or some other tcpdump equivalent program and verify that the [mDNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) packets being broadcast by your Apple TV are being seen by client programs running on your PC. You can power cycle the Apple TV or just exit and re-join the network while capturing to ensure it's not a network or firewall issue.

Once that's decided, you can look into iTunes drivers or software conflicts or address the networking issue as your specific circumstances dictate.

Comment: I ran WinDump and it printed _listening on device_ followed by a device name. I restarted the AppleTV (cold boot). Nothing came out in the WinDump window.

Answer (score 0):

It seems everybody is having problems with this, including myself. You could try to:

- Change wireless security from WPA to WEP (couldn't test)
- Turn off wireless sync between your iDevices and iTunes (did no good)
- Reinstall Bonjour (unistalling everything Apple/iTunes related and then installing iTunes again didn't help me)
- Restart "Apple Mobile Device" service on your Windows computer (again no good)
- Buy a Mac ;) - it seems it all comes down to this

Comment: Before downvoting, did any of you try the mentioned steps? There are claims they helped others. I resorted to the last solution.